# LibGDX create label for ingame shop

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a shop where you can buy things. So everything is set up. But I want to print a text that says you need so much for this item, on the bottom of the screen. Like the user clicks an item that costs 500 coins, and if he doesn't have enough it prints a text at the bottom sayin "You need 500 coins!".

The thing is that I could once again code it all myself... But I am sure there is a faster way, like an already in-built method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is tutorial how to write text in libGDX

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/09/26/LibGDX-Tutorial-2-Hello-World.aspx

Basically you should create font object, use it to set font, color, size and stuff and finally for writing text out:

```
    font = new BitmapFont();
// Or for some custom font
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/arial-15.fnt"),false);

    font.setColor(Color.RED);

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "Hello World", 200, 200);
    batch.end();
```

For converting "normal" fonts to ones you can use with LibGDX there are free tools, i.e. Hiero:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero